# How do I filter values in an object to display an array of values

Tags: javascript

How do I fix my honorRoll function at the bottom so that it displays the names of all the students with GPA higher than the benchmark of 3.5?

Right now all I get back is an empty array, I would like to see [Bianca Pargas, Sameer Fares].

```js
const GPA_BENCHMARK = 3.5;

let students = {
  1: {
    name: 'Egill Vignission',
    gpa: 3.4
  },
  2: {
    name: 'Bianca Pargas',
    gpa: 3.8
  },
  3: {
    name: 'Aisling O\'Sullivan',
    gpa: 3.4
  },
  4: {
    name: 'Sameer Fares',
    gpa: 3.9
  }
}

let honorRoll = Object.values(students).filter(student => {
  return students.gpa >= GPA_BENCHMARK;
});

console.log(honorRoll);
```

Comment: `students.gpa` ----> `student.gpa`

Comment: There's no good reason to use an object with numeric properties instead of an array.  The reason your filter doesn't work is because you are trying to access students.gpa, which doesn't exist.  student.gpa does.

Comment: You should not use real names (it can make legal differences).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a very simple way you can do like that

```
const GPA_BENCHMARK = 3.5;

let students = {
  1: {
    name: 'Egill Vignission',
    gpa: 3.4,
  },
  2: {
    name: 'Bianca Pargas',
    gpa: 3.8,
  },
  3: {
    name: "Aisling O'Sullivan",
    gpa: 3.4,
  },
  4: {
    name: 'Sameer Fares',
    gpa: 3.9,
  },
};

let honorRoll = [];
for (let key in students) { 
  if (students[key].gpa >= GPA_BENCHMARK) {
    honorRoll.push(students[key]);
  }
}

console.log(honorRoll);
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `students` instead of `student` in your filter fn